# bigquery SQL, aggregate based on quota value

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, window-functions, cumulative-sum, quota

Problem :

- So I have a table containing quota batch of a product. For 1 product, it will have several quota_id with each quota_id has different value of quota. Please find this table in CTE **quota**
- Then I have a table of purchase, which need to be joined with quota table and aggregate it. The purchase is aggregated to fill the first batch(the first is batch with earlier batch_date), then moved to second batch when the quota is full. Refer to CTE **purchase**

SQL :

```
WITH quota AS (
select 'Product A' as product, 'Quota_batch_1' as quota_id, 10 as quota, '2022-01-01' as batch_date
UNION All
select 'Product A' as product, 'Quota_batch_2' as quota_id, 20 as quota, '2022-02-01' as batch_date
),

purchase as (
  select '2022-01-01' as sales_date, 5 as qty, 'sales_1' as sales_id, 'Product A' as product, 100 as price
  UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-01' as sales_date, 5 as qty, 'sales_2' as sales_id, 'Product A' as product, 150 as price
  UNION ALL
  select '2022-02-03' as sales_date, 2 as qty, 'sales_3' as sales_id, 'Product A' as product, 200 as price
)
select 
quota.*,
sum(qty) as quota_filled_by_qty,
sum(price) as total_price

from quota
left join purchase using (product)
group by 1,2,3,4
```

**Expected result** :
[image]

I have no idea to do the join or the aggregation, as my current result is still aggregated for all result. I've explored like using analytical function, cumulative sum etc but still unable to crack the problem.

**Current result** :
[image]

Any idea? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using [`LEAD` navigation function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lead) and adjusting your `JOIN` condition:

```sql
WITH quota AS (
select 'Product A' as product, 'Quota_batch_1' as quota_id, 10 as quota, '2022-01-01' as batch_date
UNION All
select 'Product A' as product, 'Quota_batch_2' as quota_id, 20 as quota, '2022-02-01' as batch_date
),
purchase as (
  select '2022-01-01' as sales_date, 5 as qty, 'sales_1' as sales_id, 'Product A' as product, 100 as price
  UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-01' as sales_date, 5 as qty, 'sales_2' as sales_id, 'Product A' as product, 150 as price
  UNION ALL
  select '2022-02-03' as sales_date, 2 as qty, 'sales_3' as sales_id, 'Product A' as product, 200 as price
),
quota_next_batch as (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    LEAD(batch_date) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY batch_date) as next_batch_date
  FROM quota
)
SELECT 
  q.product,
  q.quota_id,
  q.quota,
  q.batch_date,
  SUM(p.qty) as quota_filled_by_qty,
  SUM(p.price) as total_price
FROM quota_next_batch q 
LEFT JOIN purchase p
  ON p.product = q.product AND p.sales_date >= q.batch_date AND (q.next_batch_date IS NULL OR p.sales_date < q.next_batch_date)
GROUP BY q.product, q.quota_id, q.quota, q.batch_date
```

Output:

```
product     quota_id        quota   batch_date  quota_filled_by_qty total_price
Product A   Quota_batch_1   10      2022-01-01  10                  250
Product A   Quota_batch_2   20      2022-02-01  2                   200
```

Comment: Waw that's great! I might be adjusting a little bit where I will read from `quota_next_batch` first then left join `purchase` to ensure all the quota is listed in the output regardless of having purchase or not. is it ok?

Comment: I think this is ok, I will adjust the answer